# ¿Cómo exportar a ejecutable una aplicación con conexión a una BD (mdf)?

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, vb.net, .net, github-desktop

Realicé un pequeño sistema para el control de cliente y sus compras. Este sistema conecta a una BD (.mdf)

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo genero un ejecutable que incluya dicha BD y, además, qué requerimientos deben tener las máquinas donde voy a instalar el sistema para no tener problemas de conexión a la BD?

Comment: ¿Un MDF? ¿No será el formato físico de una base de datos de SQL Server?

Comment: Si pero cuando inicié el desarrollo lo hice en un ambiente donde tenia SQL Server, no creo que deba instalarlo en todas las máquinas para que mi aplicación funcione. Así que preguntando qué hacer me dijeron que realizara el proyecto con conexion a ese archivo mdf, en lugar del localhost (no se si me explico bien :( ... ) mi duda es, como instalo la aplicación en otras máquinas con la BD portable o que vaya en la aplicación. Me expliqué? :(

Comment: El tema es que tu aplicación no accede al MDF sino al motor de la base de datos, trasladar un MDF no sirve de nada si no tienes un servidor SQL Server corriendo en forma local en el equipo o centralizada en un servidor. En caso que lo tuvieras, la forma más sencilla de trasladar una base es haciendo un backup y luego un restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aun el connection string acceda directo a un archivo .mdf requieres del servicio de `Sql Server` local en la pc del usuario para que el attach dinamico pueda realizarse.

Es por eso que en la instalacion vas a tenen que incluir el instalador del `Sql Server Express`.

No se si la aplicacion sera ejecutada de form individual por cada usuario, porque si es asi y no quieres instalar el servicio de sql server, deberias utilizar `Sql Compact`, este no requiere servicio y accedes a un archivo `.sdf`

Para administrar esta db utilizas la extension del Visual Studio
[SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox)

Utilizando una db en Sql Compact no necesitas servicio, y ado.net es casi identido, solo cambia `SqlConnection` por `SqlCeConnection`, `SqlCommand` por `SqlCeCommand`

[My First Experience With SqlServer CE 4.0](http://peterkellner.net/2011/09/02/my-first-experience-with-sqlserver-ce-4-0/)

Comment: 0
votar en contra
accept
Leandro Gracias, es justo la orientación que necesito. Gracias.

Solo basta entonces con incluir el instalador de Sql Server Express verdad?

Saludos, buen día

Comment: exacto, si el connection string define un mdf requieres que el servicio de sql server este instalado localmente en la pc